# Rewriting function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the following (working) function in JavaScript:

```js
function solve(strArr) {
  return strArr.reduce(function ([x, y], curr) {
    switch (curr) {
      case 'up':    return [x, y + 1]
      case 'down':  return [x, y - 1]
      case 'left':  return [x - 1, y]
      case 'right': return [x + 1, y]
    }
  }, [0, 0])
}
```

I'm trying to rewrite it using TypeScript as:

```
function solve(strArr: string[]): number[] {
  return strArr.reduce(([x, y]: number[], curr: string) =>  {
    switch (curr) {
      case 'up': return [x, y + 1]
      case 'down': return [x, y - 1]
      case 'left': return [x - 1, y]
      case 'right': return [x + 1, y]
    }
  }, [0,0])
}
```

but I'm getting the `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.` error, which I know refers to the accumulator, but don't know how to solve.

As per [Rajesh's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74581153/rewriting-function-in-typescript#comment131647782_74581153), changing the type of `strArr` to `any` solves the issue, but giving it the specific type I'm using with the function doesn't work; why?

Comment: function solve(strArr : any ) {

any solves all problems, But try to replace it later

Comment: @RajeshKanna true, it solves it. What do you mean by replacing it later?

Comment: Since .reduce() method is generic it accepts almost all types that has the length attributes. So you are on the safe side. But giving a function a specific type for the parameter helps you use TypeScript's strong typing feature to the fullest.

Comment: If you're going to use TypeScript, _use TypeScript_ - specify the types of parameters and return values. If `strArr` isn't more specific than `string[]`, then your reducer _doesn't_ always return `number[]` (shouldn't that be `[number, number]`?)

Comment: @RajeshKanna edited the question to reflect your solution. Still don't get why being specific throws the error...

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure what you mean by your smirky comment. The 1st function I wrote is written in JavaScript, not TS.

Comment: If you're more specific about what you're expecting the _reducer_ to return, the compiler can be more specific about why it thinks you're wrong. From the first revision it wasn't clear what if any type metadata you'd tried adding.

Comment: @jonrsharpe where do I specify the type of the return value of `reduce`?

Comment: Of the _reducer_: https://tsplay.dev/m33Abm. You either need to handle the default case, as the answers below suggest (but I think returning in that case is the wrong move), or narrow the input to tell the compiler they're the only four possible strings in the array.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, tried adding it there before, but you still get the squigly red line, so that doesn't solve it. Adding the default case does. Then I agree, specifying the return type looks nicer.

Comment: Right, that's not the _solution_; my point is that if you give the compiler the information it needs to help you the squiggly red line then comes with a **more useful error**: _"Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'. (2366)"_ As I said above, the compiler can be more specific about why it thinks you're wrong.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Because you are not covering all cases.

Add the default case to the switch

`default : return []`

Answer (score 3):

You can add a default case for your switch as others have suggested.

I would advise a second solution, which is to create a type for your input parameter to narrow the type:

```
type Direction = 'up' | 'down' | 'left' | 'right'

function solve(strArr: Direction[]) {
  return strArr.reduce(([x, y], curr) =>  {
    switch (curr) {
      case 'up': return [x, y + 1]
      case 'down': return [x, y - 1]
      case 'left': return [x - 1, y]
      case 'right': return [x + 1, y]
    }
  }, [0,0])
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgJwgY2HA9gOygXigcgFcx8oAfAgE3QHdNSL8AbCAM2AYITgHMALDgChBrQplQZsAZ3RMAbhAAUU4AgCCCBAC54SCVgDaAXQCUUAN6CoUJMEIJpqjQgB0SSoWRLFBgB4AaKBAjQOR7BDMcAD5rS2trKRo4YGQ%20KEUwzTM4%20OtkAEMpaCISLRsIOwcoP0CQKABqKABGIytcqAKiqlp6Mtt7bBqgqABaZtb2jsLilnZ8PoqB6t9R5tqJ9s7i7n4OBcrBlcam9bbrAF8288CDAAZ-W9NBc6A)

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly handle the default case in your switch:

```js
function solve(strArr:string[]) {
  return strArr.reduce(([x, y], curr) =>  {
    switch (curr) {
      case 'up': return [x, y + 1]
      case 'down': return [x, y - 1]
      case 'left': return [x - 1, y]
      case 'right': return [x + 1, y]
      // maybe throw an error instead
      default: return [x, y];
    }
  }, [0,0])
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgGwG4FMAUyoBOAggQQFz4ExgDmA2gLoCUiA3gFCKIFZQgFJKJAgDoeAExARcOOgA8ANIgCeDJRH4EWAXgB8XDly7IA7jCgQAFohwbSLQ0a4QAhsiyIA5CAAOnsty8-EjySsqIANSIAIwMnE6Iru5e4nAmYP6BfAKIoSqIALQxcQmJbh6eaFjAUJk82SFyhTFhJQlJFVQ0lrUB9cG5TVHRrfFOAPTjiAC2LsoARh5QlgRpiC5IWKRwBIjU+Fgu4mNG4tUuIGhQfUE5eaoA3CcAvvHPSnQADAqfzOzPQA)

without the default case your reducer function returns the type: `number[] | undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can improve params and return types.

For the code's readability, you should avoid `array.reduce()`.

```js
type Direction = 'up' | 'down' | 'left' | 'right'
function solve(directions: Direction[]): [number, number] {
  let x = 0
  let y = 0
  for (const direction of directions) {
    switch (direction) {
      case 'up': y++; break
      case 'down': y--; break
      case 'left': x--; break
      case 'right': x++; break
    }
  }
  return [x, y]
}
```